# ruamel condensing comments and injecting 0x07

Tags: yaml, ruamel.yaml

Given the following code:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml = YAML()
with open(filename) as f:
    z = yaml.load(f)
yaml.dump(z, sys.stdout)
```

And the following file:

```
a: >
  Hello.<b>
  World.
```

When `<b>` is a space character (`0x20`), produces the following YAML:

```
a: >
  Hello. <0x07> World.
```

When `<0x07>` is the byte `0x07`.
Trying to re-load this YAML using PyYAML results in an error as `0x07` is an invalid character.

This does not happen when I remove the trailing blank after the `Hello.` in the input YAML.

Any idea what can cause this?

Comment: You likely have a buggy ruamel version installed. I had the same issue, and it was fixed in version 0.15.66: https://pypi.org/project/ruamel.yaml/0.15.66/ See the comment in the changelog

Comment: @tinita I'm using `0.15.79`, which, AFAIK, is the latest. Also, I'm able to reproduce this with `0.15.66` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BEL character (`0x07`, `\a`) is inserted during parsing in block style folded strings, so that the representation for that scalar in Python (`ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.FoldedScalarString`) can register the positions where the original folds did occur. At dump time, the reverse is done: the positions are translated to BEL characters (if they correspond to spaces) and so transmit these folding positions from the representer to the emitter, which then outputs the scalar with the "folds" at the original points the occurred. This of course can/should only happen if the positions still represent "foldable" positions.

The problem here is that the parser should, during loading, complain that your YAML is incorrect. It fails to do so, loads faulty data and then fails to properly dump the mess it allowed to be loaded in the first place, resulting in the BEL character ending up in the output.

The [YAML specification](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2796251) states:

> Folding allows long lines to be broken anywhere a single space character separates two non-space characters.

And as your line has not been folded between two non-space characters, this should  result in a warning, if not in an immediate parser error.¹

Additionally the representer should of course be smart enough not to replace a space by a  BEL character if the space it is replacing is adjacent to white-space. That situation can also occur after changing a string that was loaded from correct YAML with a folded string. I essentially consider that a bug.

The  ruamel.yaml>0.15.80 has a fix for the incorrect representation. An implementation on the error/warning on loading is likely to follow soon.

---

¹ <sub>When only issuing a warning, my initial reaction is that I should strip the faulty trailing space, or spaces in case there are more, because it is invisible, and keeping the fold.</sub>